# why signal/slot not working with multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qthread

```
class A : public QObject{

  Q_OBJECT

signals:
  void a_sig();

public:
  A(){ }

public slots:
  void begin(){
    QObject::connect(&_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SIGNAL(a_sig()));
    _timer.start(1000); 
  }

private:
  QTimer _timer;
};


class B : public QObject{

  Q_OBJECT

public:
  B(){ value = 0; }

public slots:
  void b_slot(){

    ++value;
    QFile file("out.txt");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << value << "\n";
    file.close();
  }

private:
  int value;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

  A a;
  B b;
  QThread aThread;
  QThread bThread;

  QObject::connect(&aThread, SIGNAL(started()), &a, SLOT(begin()));
  QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(a_sig()), &b, SLOT(b_slot()));

  a.moveToThread(&aThread);
  b.moveToThread(&bThread);

  aThread.start();
  bThread.start();

  return app.exec();
}
```

I'm trying to understand why `b_slot()` isn't getting called.  Can anyone explain what's happening, and why `b_slot()` isn't getting called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the ownership of the `_timer` member of the `A` class.

Since you're not explicitly initializing it, it is initialized without a parent object. So the `a.moveToThread(&aThread)` isn't moving the timer to `aThread`, and things get confused after that.

Change `A`'s constructor to:

```
A() : _timer(this) {}
```

and your `b_slot()` will get called.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that while object `a` is moved to `aThread`, `_timer` object still belongs to the original main thread. Try initializing `_timer` inside `begin` method like that:

```
  void begin() {
    _timer = new QTimer;
    QObject::connect(_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SIGNAL(a_sig()));
    _timer->start(1000); 
  }

private:

  QTimer *_timer;
```